# Android: How much overhead is generated by running an empty method?

Tags: java, android, performance, overhead

I have created a class to handle my debug outputs so that I don't need to strip out all my log outputs before release.

```
public class Debug {
    public static void debug( String module, String message) {
        if( Release.DEBUG )
            Log.d(module, message);
    }
}
```

After reading another question, I have learned that the contents of the if statement are not compiled if the constant Release.DEBUG is false.

What I want to know is how much overhead is generated by running this empty method? (Once the if clause is removed there is no code left in the method) Is it going to have any impact on my application? Obviously performance is a big issue when writing for mobile handsets =P

Thanks

Gary

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Measurements done on Nexus S with Android 2.3.2:

```
10^6 iterations of 1000 calls to an empty static void function: 21s  <==> 21ns/call
10^6 iterations of 1000 calls to an empty non-static void function: 65s  <==> 65ns/call

10^6 iterations of 500 calls to an empty static void function: 3.5s  <==> 7ns/call
10^6 iterations of 500 calls to an empty non-static void function: 28s  <==> 56ns/call

10^6 iterations of 100 calls to an empty static void function: 2.4s  <==> 24ns/call
10^6 iterations of 100 calls to an empty non-static void function: 2.9s  <==> 29ns/call
```

control:

```
10^6 iterations of an empty loop: 41ms <==> 41ns/iteration
10^7 iterations of an empty loop: 560ms <==> 56ns/iteration
10^9 iterations of an empty loop: 9300ms <==> 9.3ns/iteration
```

I've repeated the measurements several times. No significant deviations were found.
You can see that the per-call cost can vary greatly depending on workload (possibly due to JIT compiling), 
but 3 conclusions can be drawn:

1. dalvik/java sucks at optimizing dead code
2. static function calls can be optimized much better than non-static 
   (non-static functions are virtual and need to be looked up in a virtual table)
3. the cost on nexus s is not greater than 70ns/call (thats ~70 cpu cycles) 
   and is comparable with the cost of one empty for loop iteration (i.e. one increment and one condition check on a local variable)

Observe that in your case the string argument will always be evaluated. If you do string concatenation, this will involve creating intermediate strings. This will be very costly and involve a lot of gc.  For example executing a function:

```
void empty(String string){
}
```

called with arguments such as

```
empty("Hello " + 42 + " this is a string " + count );
```

10^4 iterations of 100 such calls takes 10s. That is 10us/call, i.e. ~1000 times slower than just an empty call. It also produces huge amount of GC activity. The only way to avoid this is to manually inline the function, i.e. use the >>if<< statement instead of the debug function call. It's ugly but the only way to make it work.

Comment: yeah It's really the stringbuilder that bites you if you have uncommented. the reason is that the runtime jit or aot compiler can't determine ahead of time if the string creation will fail, affecting the flow of the program.

an if around it is messy. a pre-compiler would be the right way but right now there is no easy way to do that with the android default tools, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you call this from within a deeply nested loop, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

A good compiler removes the entire empty method, resulting in no overhead at all. I'm not sure if the Dalvik compiler already does this, but I suspect it's likely, at least since the arrival of the Just-in-time compiler with Froyo.

See also: [Inline expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion#Selection_methods_and_language_support)

Comment: Get yourself a copy of apktool, decompile your app and see if it's been optimized out of the dalvik bytecode.  There are later stages where it could be optimized during installation or runtime loading, but that seems the most obvious one.

Comment: if you decompile the apk you don't actually see the art or dalvik optimizations, you see only the optimizations done by the java compiler and dex converter(and possibly proguard). you would need to extract the cached stuff from further inside.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance the overhead of generating the messages which get passed into the debug function are going to be a lot more serious since its likely they do memory allocations eg

```
Debug.debug(mymodule, "My error message" + myerrorcode);
```

Which will still occur even through the message is binned.
Unfortunately you really need the  "if( Release.DEBUG ) " around the calls to this function rather than inside the function itself if your goal is performance, and you will see this in a lot of android code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and I like @misiu_mp analysis, so I thought I would update it with a 2016 test on a Nexus 7 running Android 6.0.1. Here is the test code:

```
public void runSpeedTest() {
    long startTime;
    long[] times = new long[100000];
    long[] staticTimes = new long[100000];
    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            emptyMethod();
        }
        times[i] = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            emptyStaticMethod();
        }
        staticTimes[i] = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000;
    }
    int timesSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) { timesSum += times[i]; Log.d("status", "time," + times[i]); sleep(); }
    int timesStaticSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) { timesStaticSum += staticTimes[i]; Log.d("status", "statictime," + staticTimes[i]); sleep(); }
    sleep();
    Log.d("status", "final speed = " + (timesSum / times.length));
    Log.d("status", "final static speed = " + (timesStaticSum / times.length));
}

private void sleep() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void emptyMethod() { }
private static void emptyStaticMethod() { }
```

The `sleep()` was added to prevent overflowing the `Log.d` buffer.

I played around with it many times and the results were pretty consistent with @misiu_mp:

```
10^5 iterations of 1000 calls to an empty static void function: 29ns/call
10^5 iterations of 1000 calls to an empty non-static void function: 34ns/call
```

The static method call was always slightly faster than the non-static method call, but it would appear that a) the gap has closed significantly since Android 2.3.2 and b) there's still a cost to making calls to an empty method, static or not.

Looking at a histogram of times reveals something interesting, however. The majority of call, whether static or not, take between 30-40ns, and looking closely at the data they are virtually all 30ns exactly.

[image]

Running the same code with empty loops (commenting out the method calls) produces an average speed of 8ns, however, about 3/4 of the measured times are 0ns while the remainder are exactly 30ns.

I'm not sure how to account for this data, but I'm not sure that @misiu_mp's conclusions still hold. The difference between empty static and non-static methods is negligible, and the preponderance of measurements are exactly 30ns. That being said, it would appear that there is still some non-zero cost to running empty methods.

Comment: if you add a String creation to the calling method, like a typical debug message would be "status"+int, I think you would see no difference at all(even though nothing is done with the string inside the static method).